# Should I use multiple canvases (HTML 5) or use divs to display HUD data?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am in process of making a game where the health bar (animated) and some other info represented visually like some icons showing the number of bombs the player has etc. Now, this can be done both in canvas (by making another canvas for info that sits over the main canvas, or it can be done using many divs and spans with absolute positioning. This is my first time in making a browser based game so if any experienced people view this, tell me what you recommend. **I would like to know that which method would be faster.**

The game will also be running on mobile devices. Thanks!

Comment: Does your game animate itself in <canvas> (the game world)? In that case I suggest you draw also HUD elements inside the canvas, to have the graphics code work in more coherent manner.

Comment: I prefer to use another container element that sits on top of the main canvas which runs the game. The reason is that, this seems simpler and it enables me to hide the info whenever I want and then pop it back up later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the canvas. Use two canvases if you want, one overlaid over the other, but use the canvas.

Touching the DOM at all is slow. Making the document redo its layout because the size of DOM elements moved is very slow. Dealing with the canceling (or not) of even more events because there are DOM items physically on top of the canvas can be a pain and why bother dealing with that?

If your HUD does not update very often then the fastest thing to do would be drawing it to an in-memory canvas when it changes, and then always drawing that canvas to the main canvas when you update the frame. In that way your drawHud method will look exactly like this:

```
function drawHUD() {
  // This is what gets called every frame
  // one call to drawImage = simple and fast
  ctx.drawImage(inMemoryCanvas, 0, 0);
}
```

and of course updating the HUD information would be like:

```
function updateHUD() {
  // This is only called if information in the HUD changes
  inMemCtx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  inMemCtx.fillRect(blah);
  inMemCtx.drawImage(SomeHudImage, x, y);
  var textToDraw = "Actually text is really slow and if there's" + 
                   "often repeated lines of text in your game you should be" +
                   "caching them to images instead";
  inMemCtx.fillText(textToDraw, x, y);
}
```

Since HUDs often contain text I really do urge caching it if you're using any. [More on text performance here](http://simonsarris.com/blog/322-canvas-drawtext-considered-harmful).

Comment: No (full) DOM reflow will be needed when absolute (or even fixed) positioned elements are redrawn.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I didn't know that drawing text on canvas causes performance issues. I'll definitely be doing something similar to your solution.

Answer (score 7):

There is no straighforward answer and I suggest you do FPS testing with different browser how it plays out for your use case. If you do not wish to go such in-depth I suggest you simply draw the elements inside canvas and if you need to hide them then leave out drawHUD() call from your rendering loop.

For HTML HUD overlay on `<canvas>` the following factors should be considered

- Can the web browser compositor do hardware accelerated `<canvas>` properly if there are DOM elements upon the canvas
- HTML / DOM manipulation will be always slower than `<canvas>` operations due to inherited complexity dealing with DOM elements
- `<canvas>` pixel space stays inside `<canvas>` and it might be difficult to have pixel-perfect aligment if you try to draw elements on `<canvas>` outside the canvas itself
- HTML offers much more formatting options for text than canvas drawString() - is HTML formatting necessary

Comment: very nice! I dont know why I didnt think about leaving out the drawHUD() call from the rendering loop :P After reading your answer, I think I'll be going with the draw on main canvas option

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, there is no universally best approach, as it depends on the specifics of what you need to render, how often, and possibly what messaging needs to happen between graphical components.

While it is true the DOM reflows are expensive, this blanket warning is not always applicable. For instance, using position:fixed; elements avoids triggering reflows for the page (not necessarily within the element if there are non-fixed children). Repaint is (correct me if this is wrong) expensive because it is pixel pushing, and so is not intrinsically slower than pushing the same number of pixels to a canvas. It can be faster for some things. What's more, each has certain operations that have performance advantages over the other.

Here are some points to consider:

It's increasingly possible to use WebGL-accelerated canvas elements on many A-grade browsers. This works fine for 2D, with the advantage that drawing operations are sent to the GPU, which is MUCH faster than the 2D context. However this may not be available on some target platforms (e.g., at the time of this writing, it is available in iOS Safari but not in the iOS UIWebView used if you target hybrid mobile applications.) Using a library to wrap canvas can abstract this and use WebGL if its available. Take a look at pixi.js.

Conversely, the DOM has CSS3 animations/transitions which are typically hardware-accelerated by the GPU automatically (with no reliance on WebGL). Depending on the type of animation, you can often get much faster results this way than with canvas, and often with simpler code.

Ultimately, as a rule in software performance, understanding the algorithms used is critical. That is, regardless of which approach used, how are you scheduling animation frames? Have you looked in a profiler to see what things take the most time? This practice is *excellent* for understanding what is impacting performance.

I've been working on an app with multiple animations, and have implemented each component both as DOM and canvas. I was initially surprised that the DOM version was higher performant than the canvas (wrapped with KineticJS) version, though I know see that this was because all the animated elements were position:fixed and using CSS (under the hood via jQuery UI), thereby getting GPU performance. However the code to manage these elements felt clunky (in my case, ymmv). Using a canvas approach allows more pixel-perfect rendering, but then it loses the ability to style with CSS (which technically allows pixel-perfect rendering as well but may be more or less complex to achieve).

I achieved a big speed up by throttling the most complex animation to a lower framerate, which for my case is indistinguishable from the 60fps version but runs smooth as butter on an older iPad 2. Throttling required using requestAnimationFrame and clamping calls to be no more often than the desired framerate. This would be hard to do with CSS animations on the DOM (though again, these are intrinsically faster for many things). The next thing I'm looking at is syncing multiple canvas-based components to the same requestAnimationFrame loop (possibly independently throttled, or a round-robin approach where each component gets a set fraction of the framerate, which may work okay for 2-3 elements. (Incidentally, I have some GUI controls like sliders that are not locked to any framerate as they are should be as close to 60fps as possible and are small/simple enough that I haven't seen performance issues with them).

I also achieved a huge speed boost by profiling and seeing that one class in my code that had *nothing* to do with the GUI was having a specific method called very often to calculate a property. The class in question was immutable, so I changed the method to memoize the value and saw the CPU usage drop in half. Thanks Chrome DevTools and the flame chart! Always profile.

Most of the time, the number of pixels being updated will tend to be the biggest bottleneck, though if you can do it on the GPU you have effectively regained all the CPU for your code. DOM reflows should be avoided, but this does not mean avoid the DOM. Some elements are far simpler to render using the DOM (e.g. text!) and may be optimized by the browser's (or OS's) native code more than canvas. Finally, if you can get acceptable performance for a given component using either approach (DOM or canvas), use the one that makes the code simplest for managing that type of component.

Best advice is to try isolated portions in the different approaches, run with a profiler, use techniques to over-draw or otherwise push the limits to see which approach can run fastest, and do NOT optimize before you have to. The caveat to this rule is the question you are asking: how do I know in advance which technical approach is going to allow the best performance? If you pick one based on *assuming* the answer, you are basically prematurely optimizing and will live with the arbitrary pain this causes. If instead you are picking by rapid prototyping or (even better) controlled experiments that focus on the needs of your application, you are doing R&D :)

Answer (score 1):

[Browserquest](http://browserquest.mozilla.org/) displays their HUD using HTML elements, which  has the benefit that you don't have to worry about redrawing etc. (and the performance will be pretty good, given that the entire browser engine is optimized to render the DOM pretty fast.

They (browserquest) also use several layered canvas elements for different game elements. I don't know the exact structure, but I guess that on which canvas an element is displayed depends on how often it needs to be redrawn.